# Connecting iSeries JDBC to Microsoft Azure SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, azure, jdbc, ibm-midrange

I have used Scott Klement's example code to create a connection from our iSeries (level V5R2M0) using jtds-1.3.1.jar to our Azure SQL Server. Scott's example RPG ILE program MSSQLTEST gets as far as the connection value test which fails as it is always Null. The Java software successfully loads and shows no errors. The following is the code in question:

```
prop = JDBC_Properties();

JDBC_setProp(prop: 'userName'     : 'dbadmin@mssqlserver');
JDBC_setProp(prop: 'password'     : 'password');
JDBC_setProp(prop: 'databaseName' : 'SQLDatabase');
JDBC_setProp(prop: 'encrypt'      : 'true');
JDBC_setProp(prop: 'hostNameInCertificate' : '*.database.windows.net');
JDBC_setProp(prop: 'loginTimeout' : '30');

conn = JDBC_ConnProp('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
:'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mssqlserver.database.windows.net:1433'
: prop );

JDBC_freeProp(prop);

if (conn = *NULL);
return;
endif;
```

The connection parameters were provided by Microsoft as:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://mssqlserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=Database;user=dbadmin@mssqlserver;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

I have tried the following to try and make the connection work:

Added a port forward on our router for port 1433 which points to our iSeries IP address

Added our external IP address to our Azure SQL Server firewall

I have tested the connection parameters by creating an ODBC connection to our Azure SQL Server on a PC which works

Does anyone have this working between the iSeries and Azure SQL Server?

Comment: `Added a port forward on our router for port 1433 which points to our iSeries IP address` ??? Why? You don't have it on your iSeries, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used jTDS, but from my experience Microsoft recommends us to use SQL Server JDBC (sqljdbc.jar or sqljdbc4.jar) to connect to Azure SQL Database from Java. You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg715284.aspx for a sample and you may want to check out http://as400blog.blogspot.mx/2009/09/need-to-access-ms-sql-databases-from.html to see how to leverage this driver.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the connection string provided by the Azure portal, the key word for user is `user`, not `userName`. Once I set the value for `user` using `JDBC_setprop`, it worked for me.